# Iterate through JSON array (App Crashing)

Tags: objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to iterate trough a JSON array to get both the item key and value.

This is my JSON array:

```
 {
    "ClientData": [{
        "Name": "Michael"
    }, {
        "Last": "Ortiz"
    }, {
        "Phone": "5555555555"
    }, {
        "email": "test@gmail.com"
    }],
    "ClientAccess": [{
        "T-Shirt": "YES"
    }, {
        "Meals": "NO"
    }, {
        "VIP": "YES"
    }, {
        "Registration Completed": "Pending"
    }]
}
```

Now, I am trying to iterate through the "ClientData" array, but for some reason the app is crashing with this exception:

```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

This is the code I am using to iterate through the JSON array:

```
NSDictionary* object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

// Client Profile Data

NSDictionary *clientDataDict = [object objectForKey:@"ClientData"];
for (id item in clientDataDict) 
{
    [JSONUserData addObject:[clientDataDict objectForKey:item]];
}
```

This code was working fine when I didn't have each item on the JSON array placed inside an array. I did this to keep a consecutive order on the array.

Can someone give me any pointers on what the problem is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClientData` is an array – represented by the square brackets `[]` – containing dictionaries with one key/value pair respectively (a quite cumbersome structure).

```
NSDictionary* object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

// Client Profile Data

NSArray *clientDataArray = [object objectForKey:@"ClientData"];
for (NSDictionary *dict in clientDataArray) {
   for (NSString *key in dict) {
      [JSONUserData addObject:[dict objectForKey:key]];
   }
}
```

Comment: If at all possible, talk to the people responsible for generating the JSON and ask them what on earth they are up to. An array of dictionaries, each dictionary with a single key-value pair, that's just ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

According to your JSON strings, it looks like that ClientData pairs with an array and each item in array is a dictionary. Therefore, revised codes will look like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSArray *array = [object objectForKey:@"ClientData"];
for (NSDictionary *item in array) {
    [mDict addEntriesFromDictionary:item];
}
```